# sympy not integrating properly with cosine?

Tags: python, sympy, numerical-integration, symbolic-integration

I am trying to integrate with sympy but double checking with numpy. the correct answer for this integration is zero for n=1, which the numpy version produces. But the sympy version, which should have the same answer, doesn't. can someone tell me what's wrong with the sympy version?

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp


#*******************NUMPY ATTEMPT********************************************
T = 2*np.pi
n = 1 #integer
F = lambda t: t/(2*np.pi)

wT = 2*np.pi/T #frequency

def F_An(t):
    return F(t)*np.cos(n*wT*t)
#F = lambda t: (t/(2*np.pi))*np.cos(n*wT*t)
An = quad(F_An,0,T)[0]
An = (2/T)*An
print('An numpy:', round(An,3))

#*******************SYMPY ATTEMPT********************************************
T = 2*sp.pi
n = sp.Symbol('n',integer=True,positive=True)
t = sp.symbols('t')
F = t/(2*sp.pi)

wT = 2*sp.pi/T #frequency

F_An=F*sp.cos(n*wT*t)
An = sp.integrate(F_An,t)
An = (2/T)*An
An=An.subs(t,T)
An=An.subs(n,1)
print('An sympy:', An)
```

with output:

```
An numpy: 0.0
An sympy: 1/(2*pi**2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't given limits in your call to integrate and are not using both limits. In quad you integrate from 0 to `2*pi`

```
In [17]: F_An.integrate(t)                                                                                                        
Out[17]: 
t⋅sin(n⋅t)   cos(n⋅t)
────────── + ────────
    n            2   
                n    
─────────────────────
         2⋅π         

In [18]: F_An.integrate(t).subs(t, 2*pi)                                                                                          
Out[18]: 
  1   
──────
     2
2⋅π⋅n 

In [19]: F_An.integrate(t).subs(t, 2*pi) - F_An.integrate(t).subs(t, 0)                                                           
Out[19]: 0

In [20]: F_An.integrate((t, 0, 2*pi))                                                                                             
Out[20]: 0
```